# Fancybox: div id link remove '#' and 'id' from address bar

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I have a Fancybox pop-up that adds '#' and 'id' name to the browser address bar url. 
How to keep address bar clean of this extra strings.

Following is my link:

```
   <div class="fancy_text_wrap"><a class="Fancy" id="Fancy" href="#Logins" >Sign up</a></div>
   <div style="display: none;"><div id="Logins"><?php $this->'some_link' ?></div></div>

   <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

           jQuery("a#Fancy").fancybox({
                prevEffect: 'fade',
                nextEffect: 'fade',
                closeBtn: true,

                beforeLoad: function() {                    
                window.location.hash = "";                  
                },
                beforeClose: function() {
                window.location.hash = "";
                }                 
           });

        });

        </script>
```

Comment: Please provide the FancyBox Plugin's official website URL.

Comment: fancybox 1 or 2?  If 2, then you must be doing something wrong as it shouldn't add the hash - have a look at the "Inline" link under examples: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: [Here's a fiddle of your code working](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3pjzyng0/show/), [edit the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pjzyng0/)

Comment: Its fancybox 2.1.5 and its for wordpress is that something to do with the problem.

Comment: Please say something anyone cause nothing is working.